# CSS Div boxes not going underneath eachother

Tags: html, css

i am using this CSS code for a few div boxes on my homepage:

```
#homepagebox {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
#homepagebox .column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
#homepagebox .column div {
    margin: 15px;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height:300px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background: #666666;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

I need them to start displaying underneath each other when the screen gets too small but then obviously if the screen is big enough then to all display next to each other.

at the moment if the screen is too small the boxes just get smaller

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LEvzs/

Comment: You need to specify a static `min-width` on your `.column` rule, otherwise they're always going to be 25% of their parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#homepagebox .column {
    float: left;
    min-width: 25%;
}
```

If you set your width in percentages, it will never hit the point of needing to wrap content to the next line. Setting it as min-width makes sure that they never shrink below that point and will therefore wrap.

[edit] update fiddle to have a fixed width but still wrap when needed.

```
#homepagebox .column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LEvzs/2/

Comment: hmm - ok by doing that the boxes still shrink and you cannot see the content inside the boxes. any way to make it so they are a fixed width but shrinking the page still works and looks ok?

Comment: if you want a fixed width, use pixels for the minimum and keep your percentage width. See edit.